# Datalist - Show information in reverse order

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I have a datalist that shows information from a SQL table perfectly. Is there a way to show the information in reverse order?

Example:

Person1
Person2
Person3

Instead I would like:;

Person3
Person2
Person1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your SQL query to use `ORDER BY <name> DESC`.

Answer (score 1):

see the DESCENDING option of SELECT

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do it server-side you could also use the `Reverse` extension method:

```
var items = myDataList.Items;
myDataList.Items = items.Reverse();
```

or more succinctly, but less obvious:

```
myDataList.Items = myDataList.Items.Reverse();
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in VB?

Comment: @BioXhazard: just replace `var` with `Dim` in the first example and remove the semicolons. (`;`) The second example will work exactly as is once you drop the semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select PERSONS from EXAMPLE ORDER BY PERSONS DESC;
```